# Building a struct with a function

Tags: c, function, struct, dynamic, malloc

Hello i'm trying to build a function to search a car for a client by client demand.
The structure contains: model,year,price.
the client is asked to enter his demands and then the code calls a function that check if there is a car in the structure that is suitable for him.

I get error for "access violation reading error"
thanks!

```
  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10
typedef struct
{
    char model[10];
    float price;
    int year;
}car;

void findCar(car *arr[], int minYear, float maxPrice, char modelWanted, int carAmount);
int main()
{
    int carAmount;
    car* arr;
    puts("How many cars?");
    scanf("%d", &carAmount);
    arr = (car*)malloc(carAmount * sizeof(car));
    if (arr == NULL)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < carAmount; i++)
    {
        puts("Enter car details, Model, Price,Year");
        scanf("%s%f%d",arr[i].model,&arr[i].price,&arr[i].year);
    }
    char modelWanted[SIZE];
    float maxPrice;
    int minYear;
    puts("Enter wanted model,maximum price and minimum year!");
    scanf("%s%f%d", modelWanted, &maxPrice, &minYear);
    for (int i = 0; i < carAmount; i++)
        printf("Model is: %s, Price is: %.2f, Year is: %d\n", arr[i].model, arr[i].price, arr[i].year);
    findCar(&arr, minYear, maxPrice, modelWanted, carAmount);
    free(arr);
    return 1;
}

void findCar(car *arr[], int minYear, float maxPrice, char modelWanted,int carAmount)
{
    int i, counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < carAmount; i++)
        if (((strcmp(arr[i]->model, modelWanted)) == 0) && (arr[i]->year >= minYear) && (arr[i]->price <= maxPrice))
        {
            printf("Model is: %s, Price is: %.2f, Year is: %d\n", arr[i]->model, arr[i]->price, arr[i]->year);
            ++counter;
        }
    printf("We found %d cars for you!", counter);
}
```

Comment: `char modelWanted` -- did you mean `char* modelWanted`?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing pointer to array of struct

```
car *arr[]
```

so instead of accessing elements by `arr[i]->model` like you do, you should access them using `(*arr)[i].model`. The method you uses is for accessing the array of pointers to struct element, but you have pointer to array of struct.

Of course already commented `char` instead of `char*` will also cause run time error, but you should have received compiler warning for this.

Comment: Yup! Or just pass `car *arr` or `car arr[]`. There's no need for the extra level of indirection.